# Use git with Media Temple Grid Service

Tags: git, ssh, mediatemple

I've recently got some new Hosting after needing to move away from a Github hosted website as I need to run some Jekyll plugins that I obviously can't run on a git hosted site.

I got myself a media temple (grid)server. I've been trying to go through a guide they've put together here: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1594/Using+Git#gs - However I've found (through being a Windows user, perhaps?), that these steps don't seem to work for me.

It states:

> The following steps (1-6) are performed on your local machine:

It's when I hit step 5 that I'm lost. I've installed Putty so that I can gain SSH access to my server. But if this is supposedly local, how can I follow the commands if Windows doesn't have built in SSH capabilities?

```
scp -r example.git example.com@example.com:domains/git.example.com/html/example.git
```

As they don't offer support to actually use this, I'm really hoping some of you magnificent folk can help me out. I'd also like to understand exactly what the above line of code is doing, as I only understand part of it.

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY includes an `scp` analog called `pscp`. Once you've got that installed, you should be able to use the exact command from your question, simply replacing `scp` with `pscp`.

Depending on how you installed PuTTY, this may already be available on the command line. In particular, if you used the installer, `pscp.exe` should be in your installation directory. If not, download it [from the source](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and put it somewhere logical.

Alternatively, many graphical FTP clients support SCP as an alternative transport. [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) should be able to do what you want.